# Getting missing keyword error in running code on oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables, one table storing details of staff (columns are staff_id, staff_name, department_id)  and another table storing details of department (columns are department_id, department_name,  department_block_num).

I need to write a query to display names of department and staff count in each department, if staff not exist display count as 0.

Here is code

```
Select department_name, 
        case department.department_id 
             when department.department_id=staff.department_id then count(staff_name)  
        else 0 end staff_count 
From department, staff 
Group by department_name 
order by department_name;
```

Comment: Apart from the invalid `CASE` usage, your query isn't joining department and staff which is most definitely not what you want. As a rule of thumb: "*never use a comma in the from clause*"

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `LEFT JOIN` and an aggregation query:

```
select d.department_id, d.department_name, 
       count(s.department_id) as staff_count 
from department d left join
     staff s
     on d.department_id = s.department_id
group by d.department_id, d.department_name
```

Comment: Sir i need to count number of staff in the department.  Again if staff not exist in department then show it as 0

Comment: @SuperCoolBucket . . . That is what this query does.  You should study up on your SQL so you can understand it.